# Всплывающее окно под шапкой

Tags: дефект

День добрый.

Всплывающее окна, например, с причинами закрытия можно передвигать за их шапку.
Проблема в том, что можно утянуть это окно за шапку сайта и вытянуть обратно не выйдет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно кликнуть во вне, скрыть его и открыть снова - оно вернётся в центр, но выглядит как неприятный дефект.

Comment: <SOdevmode>просто не делайте это</SOdevmode>

Comment: @alexolut, Вы, случаем, не индус?

Comment: а Вы, случаем, не расист? :)

Comment: @alexolut, положительный ответ равен SO-самоубийству, так что у меня выбора на ответ нет :) Нет.